# I need run this command -> nc -l -p 80 in one termial, and this command -> fuser -k 80/tcp in second terminal trough script

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

```
$ nc -l -p 80

$ fuser -k  80/tcp
```

This command `nc -l -p 80` will be waiting response from other terminal, I need to kill that process by running `fuser -k  80/tcp` in other terminal.

How can i achieve this in single script?

Comment: do you want to kill the `nc` command or just spawn it in the background? can you give more context?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Yasir, assuming you are using gnome-terminal you can try:

From *"gnome-terminal -help"*

*-e, --command                   Execute the argument to this option inside the terminal*

```
gnome-terminal -e "nc -l -p 80" 
gnome-terminal -e "fuser -k  80/tcp"
```

Answer (score -1):

I have never tried this myself, but I think you can do it with `screen`. I think something like this will help:

```
$screen nc -l -p 80
$screen fuser -k  80/tcp
```

Answer (score -1):

$ nc -l -p 80 &

$ fuser -k  80/tcp

I got solution, i made that process daemon

Comment: That's not a daemon, it's just running in the background.

Comment: I wanted that my script to move next line after this command  nc -l -p 80, so made if bg

Comment: Thanks tripleee, its background